# Underatanding of #define in c

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

```
#define print(args) printf args
print(("Hello"));
```

I got output

```
Hello
```

If I call print it works fine.
Could you explain how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of a macro.

When you compile a program, the first step is the preprocessor.

The preprocessor finds your macro:

```
#define print(args) printf args
```

This means that if in your program you have something like

```
print(<some text>)
```

Then the value of `<some text>` will be processed as `args` from your macro, i.e. code

```
print(<some text>)
```

will be replaced with

```
printf <some text>
```

Now, you have this line of code:

```
print(("Hello"));
```

If you put `<some text>` = `args` = `("Hello")`, then preprocessor will replace

```
print(("Hello"))
```

with

```
printf ("Hello")
```

and the whole line will be:

```
printf ("Hello");
```

which is legal c code to print `Hello`.

Comment: Nice detailed answer. Still, regarding the style, this: "*first you run compiler.

Before compiler is activated, the program finds*" I feel is a bit confusing, or at least quiet unclear. What is "*the program*"? Only after having read through half of your answer you give a hint ("*the preprocessor*") what it might have been.

Comment: Imo it's misspelling. The 'program' here is probably a preprocessor. A preprocessor macros are in fact a dummy replacement of text, without any semantic/syntactic analysis (that's why macros are advised to avoid - use constexpr functions instead)